# Bank Account ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, nested-loops

My teacher showed us how to use an ArrayList to store information, but I am having trouble with it. What i do not understand is how to reference an "account" that i have stored in the array list and then apply a method to it. for example, i am trying to use the "deposit" method on an account stored in an ArrayList.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Engine
{
public static void Engine()
{
    ArrayList<BankAccount> accounts = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
    Scanner Reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    BankAccount n = new BankAccount();
    String response = Reader.nextLine();
    boolean keepGoing = true;
    while(keepGoing)
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome to The Bank of Money, what would you like to do?\n   enter code hereenter n to create a new account, enter e to use an existing account, or     enter q to quit to main menu");

        response = Reader.nextLine();
        if(response.equals("q")) keepGoing = false;
        if(response.equals("n")) accounts.add(new BankAccount());
        if(response.equals("e"))System.out.println("what is your account number?");
        String accountNum = Reader.nextLine();  

    }
    System.out.println("press 1 to deposit money");
    System.out.println("press 2 to withdraw money");
    System.out.println("press 3 to check your account balance");
    System.out.println("press 4 to check your account's interest");
    System.out.println("press 5 to quit");
    String response2 = Reader.nextLine();
    if (Reader.nextLine().equals("1"))
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<accounts.size();i++)
        {
            if (accounts.get(i).equals(accountNum))
            {
                accounts.get(i).deposit(amount);

            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

my updated code

Comment: i hope that i gave enough information, any help will be appreciated

Comment: Bank account array list, then what? We don't need what was your teacher taught?

Comment: how will u check user input? i guess switch statement will be better option and if will be also. isn't it?

Comment: if you have an id field in the BankAccount class iterate over the arraylist on each object use getter to get the id and compare it with the input id if equals perform action

Answer (score 1):

> "how do i say "if the user inputs 1, use the deposit method?"

```
if (Reader.nextLine().equals("1")
{
    // Call deposit method on correct arraylist item.
}
```

Now, I don't know the context of your program based on the code you've given, but it looks like you are giving each instance of BankAccount a bank account number..?
This is a useful identifier as they are likely all unique.
Once you have received the correct input, you can simply loop through all your bank accounts in the arraylist until you find the one with the correct account number, and call deposit on it:

```
if (Reader.nextLine().equals("1")
{
    for (int i = 0; i<accounts.size(); i++
    {
        if (accounts.get(i).getAccountNum().equals(accountNum)) // Use a getter here
        {
            accounts.get(i).deposit(amount to deposit);
        }
    }
}
```

..or something along those lines...

Comment: thanks this is really helpful, just another follow up question, i used the code that you wrote above and I think that I understand it.  I replaced "amount to deposit" with "double amount" but i am getting a syntax error called '.class' expected. I am not sure how to fix this, i am sure that the answer is fairly basic, I am just still trying to understand the fundamentals, any help will be further appreciated. Why is a class name expected, and how do I fix it?

Comment: You are calling the method of the object already , so you don't need to pass the type to the method.. Only the variable. So once you have set the amount variable to a value,  pass that variable to the method.  In other words deposit(amount)...

Comment: okay - in this line, in the bank account class public void deposit(double amount) am i defining the variable "amount" as type double in the parameters?

Comment: if i define a variable in my bank account class, for example - "private int accountNum;" why does my engine class not recognize the variable? do i need to initialize or define the variable in both classes? if so where in my program do I put this? thanks for the help

Comment: You should have a method called deposit defined in your bank account class that takes a double amount in and does something with it. You can then give that method any value when you call it provided its of type double.. You probably get the amount to deposit from user input yes?

Comment: yes, this is my bank account class =  public class BankAccount
{
    private double balance;
    private int accountNum;
    private static int count = 1000;
    public BankAccount()
    {
        balance = 0;
        accountNum = count;
        count++;
    }
    public int getAccountNum()
    {
        return accountNum;
    }
    public void deposit(double amount)
    {
        balance = balance + amount;
    }
    public void withdraw(double amount)
    {
        balance = balance - amount;
    }
    public double getBalance()
    {
        return balance;
    }
}

Comment: oh sorry, that clearly is not formatted well, i guess what I am asking, is why does my engine class does not recognize the "accountNum" variable defined in my bank account class?

Comment: Yeah so in your main method just grab some user input as you are doing and then call the method and give it the amount that the user provided.

Comment: sorry, I really don't understand, when you say "grab some user input" - how do I do that?

Comment: `String accountNum = Reader.nextLine();` is getting user input.. i edited my response above check it out.

Comment: sorry if i made this unclear, i am not having the user enter their own account number, I wrote "private static int count = 1000" and "accountNum = count" so that the first bank accountNum is 1000 and each one following is one larger.

Comment: Then you have code in your example that is redundant. You are using a Scanner object on (system.in) which is taking user input for an acc number. Did you write the code yourself? And why are you using a static variable? I suggest googling for the following before you make further enquiries on here, as if I continue with suggestions that are quite similar you will miss the point of them: static vs non-static variables, formal vs actual parameters, and the Scanner class. Message me if you really can't figure it out. In any case, the code I posted above will work if you tweak it to fit your code.

Comment: okay - the scanner object was meant to take input for deposits, withdraws, etc. I will try tweaking the program

Answer (score 0):

How would you know which BankAccount to fetch from ArrayList? Are there multiple BankAccount which is why you are storing them in ArrayList? You want to run deposit method on all the accounts in ArrayList? Need more clarity.
Still i would recommend (given this scenario) to use switch case, where cases are like Case "1": //Call to deposit method. So on and so forth.
See if this helps. Let me know if you need further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

//how do i say "if the user inputs 1, use the deposit method?

code same as you take input to add new account or use the exist.then you can get what type of action user want to perform after creating an account.

if is an existing account take account number as input and find it from arraylist

you cant get the account if you use this code

```
for(int i = 0; i<accounts.size();i++)
{
accounts.get(i).deposit(double amount);
}
```

and create a deposite function clearly for that account number